# C2015 error regarding my declaration of a FILE

Tags: c, visual-studio, file, char

My Visual Studio 2013 gives me an C2015 error:

> A character constant contains more than two characters. The limit is
>   one character for standard character constants and two characters for
>   long character constants.

with regards to:

```
spMyOutput = fopen("C:\\MyOutput.txt", "w");
```

Based on some of the searches of that error, I am not sure what I have done wrong, since `spMyOutput` was not declared as a char variable but as a `FILE`.

There might be something else that I'm doing wrong, but I'm not sure what it might be.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int nine();
void txtdoc(int count);
void main()
{
    int count;
    count = nine();
    txtdoc(count);
    system("pause");
    return;
}
int nine()
{   
    int loopcount = 9;
    int i;
    while (loopcount >= 0)
    {

        for (i = 1; i <= loopcount; i++)
        {
            printf("%d", i);
        }
        loopcount--;
        printf("\n");
    }
    return count;
}
void txtdoc(int count)
{
    FILE* spMyOutput;
    int close;
    spMyOutput = fopen("C:\\MyOutput.txt", "w");
    if (!spMyOutput)
    {
        printf("Could not open file.\a\n");
    }
    fprintf(spMyOutput, "%d\n", count);
    close = fclose(spMyOutput);
    if (close == EOF)
    {
        printf("Could not close file.\a\n");
    }
    return;
}
```

Comment: Never declare names of the standard library yourself - unless you implement a standard library. Provide a [mcve], learn [ask]. Oh, and use prototype-style function declarators and the correct signature for `main`..

Comment: to start, there are two valid and one optional way to declare the `main()` function.   They all return 'int', not 'void'.   When compiling, always enable all warnings, then fix those warnings.

Comment: this prototype declaration: `int nine();` should be: `int nine( void );`  so the prototype indicates there are no parameters,  using the current prototype says there are parameters, but 'we're not telling exactly what they are'

Comment: when writing code, do not name variables the same as known system function names (and the stdio.h file makes the 'close' a known system function name)

Comment: there is rarely, if ever, a need to check the returned value from a call to `fclose()` as there is nothing the code can do about it if the call to `fclose()` fails,

Comment: the posted code raises several warnings, none of which is about a invalid char declaration.  1) return type from main() must be 'int  2) implicit declaration of function: `system()` need to add: `#include <stdlib.h>  3) error: 'count' undeclared in function 'nine()'  Perhaps you meant 'loopcount'?

Comment: after the call to `fopen()` fails, do not try to use the file pointer as if the open were successful,  instead 1) call `perror()` not `printf()`  2) call `exit( EXIT_FAILURE );

Answer (score 0):

after correcting the compile errors and applying the comments, your code now cleanly compiles.

Note: `pause` is a windows batch file command.  a better choice would be: `getchar()`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int nine( void );
void txtdoc(int count);

int main()
{
    int count;
    count = nine();
    txtdoc(count);
    getchar();
    return 0;
}


int nine()
{
    int loopcount = 9;
    int i;
    while (loopcount >= 0)
    {

        for (i = 1; i <= loopcount; i++)
        {
            printf("%d", i);
        }
        loopcount--;
        printf("\n");
    }
    return loopcount;
}


void txtdoc(int count)
{
    FILE* spMyOutput;


    spMyOutput = fopen("C:\\MyOutput.txt", "w");
    if (!spMyOutput)
    {
        perror("Could not open file.\a\n");
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    fprintf(spMyOutput, "%d\n", count);
    fclose(spMyOutput);
}
```

here the result of running the above code. where the code will pause for a final keystroke from the user before exiting.

```
123456789
12345678
1234567
123456
12345
1234
123
12
1
```